# What are the available approaches to interconnecting simulation systems?

Tags: simulation, distributed, distributed-system

I am looking for a distributed simulation algorithm which allows me to couple multiple standalone systems. The systems I am targeting for interconnection use different formalisms, e.g. discrete time and continuous simulation paradigms. Now, the only algorithms I found were from the field of parallel discrete event simulation (PDES), such as the classical chandy/misra "null"-message protocol, which has some very undesirable problems. My question is now, what other approaches to interconnecting simulation systems besides PDES-algorithms are known i.e. can be used for interconnecting simulation systems?

Answer (score 0):

Not an algorithm, but there are two IEEE standards out there that define protocols intended to address your issue:  [High-Level Architecture (HLA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Architecture_%28simulation%29) and [Distributed Interactive Simulation (DIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Interactive_Simulation)).  HLA has a much greater presence in the analytic discrete-event simulation community where I hang out, DIS tends to get more use in training applications.  If you'd like to check out some applications papers, go to the [Winter Simulation Conference / INFORMS-sponsorted paper archive site](http://informs-sim.org) and search for HLA, you'll get 448 hits.

Be forewarned, trying to make this stuff work in general requires some pretty weird plumbing, lots of kludges, and can be very fragile.

Comment: First: Thank you for your answer. I have cosidered using HLA earlier, but at the time I have tested it, it seemed to be too complex for my purposes, since the lerning curve is very steep and there are lots of things to be taken into account which are specific to HLA and the audience it targets (mainly military discrete event real-time simulations?). For example, it took me quite some time to even set up a correct simulation run using HLA. I think my reasearch team will reject this standard, simply for complexity reasons. Terefore I am looking for more lightweight alternatives.

Comment: @xSNRG Then I can't help, sorry.  I'm unaware of any lightweight general-purpose solutions.  If you find or develop one, let me know - the ability to bridge between models would be very handy if it could be done easily.